# cin skips when a character is input

Tags: c++, character, cin

I have a program in which I must input two doubles, and it must terminate when the character '|' is entered. However, when I type the character '|' cin is skipped and the program will just run without blocking. How can I terminate the program when a character is put in?

My code is:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    bool start = true;
    while(start)
    {
        double number1, number2 = 0;
        cout << "Enter two doubles\n";
        cin >> number1 >> number2;

        if((number1 == double{'|'}) || (number2 == double{'|'}))
        {
            start = false;
        }

        cout << "The value of number1 is: " << number1 << '\n';
        cout << "The value of number2 is: " << number2 << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A number is a number is a number, and a character is a character is a character. They are not the same and you can't input character when reading numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read a `|` character into a `double` variable.  `operator>>` will fail to extract the number and will set the `failbit` on the stream, which you can test for, eg:

```cpp
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    do
    {
        double number1, number2;

        cout << "Enter two doubles\n";
        if (!(cin >> number1 >> number2))
            break;

        cout << "The value of number1 is: " << number1 << '\n';
        cout << "The value of number2 is: " << number2 << '\n';
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, read the input as strings first, and then validate the formatting afterwards as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <string>

int main()
{
    do
    {
        std::string input1, input2;
        double number1, number2;

        cout << "Enter two doubles\n";
        if (!(cin >> input1 >> input2))
            break;

        if ((input == "|") || (input2 == "|"))
            break;

        number1 = std::stod(input1);
        number2 = std::stod(input2);

        cout << "The value of number1 is: " << number1 << '\n';
        cout << "The value of number2 is: " << number2 << '\n';
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*double* is a built-in data type used to hold **numbers** from 2.3E-308 to 1.7E+308(Including decimal point numbers). On the other hand vertical slash(|) is a character. *char* can hold any singular character (For example: 'a', '7', '#', **'|'** etc.). You tried to enter a character in a double data type in your program, which is not acceptable. Use char data type instead of double.

```
//Using char
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    bool start = true;

    while(start) {
        char number1, number2;
        std :: cout << "Enter two characters\n";
        std :: cin >> number1 >> number2;

        if((number1 == '|') || (number2 == '|'))
            start = false;

        std :: cout << "The value of number1 is: " << number1 << std :: endl;
        std :: cout << "The value of number2 is: " << number2 << std :: endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here "number1" & "number2" can store a singular number, alphabet or special characters. If you want to store a double as well as characters try using "std :: string" instead of char.

```
//Using string
#include<iostream>
    
    int main() {
        bool start = true;
        
         while(start) {
            std :: string number1, number2;
            std :: cout << "Enter two characters\n";
            std :: cin >> number1 >> number2;
    
            if((number1 == "|") || (number2 == "|"))
                start = false;
    
            std :: cout << "The value of number1 is: " << number1 << std :: endl;
            std :: cout << "The value of number2 is: " << number2 << std :: endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you want a data type that can hold doubles as well as characters, you can use std :: string instead. If you do so make sure to change '|' to "|". Single quotes are used to identify chars only.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to read about data types in C++ and about strings.
Second, considering the lecture, chose the appropriate type for your input.
Something like this should solve your issue:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
  bool start = true;

 while(start)
  {
    double number1=0, number2 = 0;//here you were initializing only number2 to 0
    cout << "Enter two doubles\n";
    char condition;

    cin >> number1 >> number2;
    cin>>condition;//to continue reading doubles give it something different from |

    if(condition == '|')
     {
      start = false;
     }
    cout << "The value of number1 is: " << number1 << '\n';
    cout << "The value of number2 is: " << number2 << '\n';
  }
 return 0;
}
```